# Error Handling For A Mac/UNIX Shell Script to Backup Our Web Servers and MySQL Databases

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix

I wrote myself a shell script to backup our web servers and got it working. It navigates to the backup directory, does an rsync, a mysqldump, commits it all to a git repository for versioning and pushes it to our remote git server. I've learned that there's lots of pitfalls to writing scheduled UNIX scripts, so I'm wondering if I'm missing anything or setting myself up for disaster. How would I have it email me on any error in the entire process?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Exit on any error
set -e

LOGFILE=~/backups/web_backup-$(date +"%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S").log
touch $LOGFILE
echo "Backup started for "$(date +"%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S") | tee -a $LOGFILE

############################################################
###### BACKUP WEBSITE
############################################################


echo "Backing up Website..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE
cd ~/backups/example.org
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Cannot change directory!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi


rsync -Pav --size-only --delete --filter='P .git' --filter='P example.com.sql' backups@example.com:/path/to/example.org/ ~/backups/example.org/ 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

echo "Backing up Example.com DB..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

ssh backups@example.com "mysqldump -u user -hlocalhost -ppassword dbname > example.com.sql 


echo "Adding files to Git Repository..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE 
git add . 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE| tee -a $LOGFILE

echo "Commiting files to Git Repository..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE 
git commit -m "Backup as of "$(date +"%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S") 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

echo "Pusing Git Repo to Remote Location..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE 
git push origin master 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE


echo "Finished backing up Website..." 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

echo "Backup Finished for "$(date +"%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S")
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a report file in the script and direct all the output to it.   Check the exit status($?) of the copy and rsynch command what ever you use if the exit status is not equal to zero then using mail command mail to the address with the report file

```
mail -s "subject " -c "cc address" "to-address" < reportfile name
```